# Compile Chromium-Embedded 3 project statically with libcef_static.lib

Tags: c++, static-linking, chromium-embedded

I've downloaded CEF 3.2272.2029 from [CEF Builds](http://cefbuilds.com/) website.

It is compiled OK.

Then according to [CEF Linking different runtime libraries](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/LinkingDifferentRunTimeLibraries) I've tried to compile `cefsimple` example with `libcef_static.lib` (previously of course compiled it as in build instructions).

So, I replaced input Libraries in Visual Studio: delete `libcef.lib` and `libcef_dll_wrapper.lib` and add `libcef_static.lib`. Then there many dependencies (`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol`) was appeared.

I search for symbols in *.lib files in `chromium\src\out\Release\obj` subdirectories, add them, but there are so many of them to find all dependencies.

So, I search all of *.lib files and simply add them to Linker Input parameters. But I don't know order of importing libs.

Is there simply way or tutorial to add all necessary dependencies in correct order to compile app using `libcef_static.lib`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it; if someone will need the list too:

```
    comctl32.lib
    ffmpegsumo.lib
    winmm.lib
    ws2_32.lib
    dwmapi.lib
    setupapi.lib
    mf.lib
    mfplat.lib
    mfreadwrite.lib
    mfuuid.lib
    d3d9.lib
    dxva2.lib
    strmiids.lib
    secur32.lib
    crypt32.lib
    iphlpapi.lib
    imm32.lib
    oleacc.lib
    sensorsapi.lib
    portabledeviceguids.lib
    libcef_static.lib
    allocator.lib
    base.lib
    base_static.lib
    allocator_extension_thunks.lib
    modp_b64.lib
    dynamic_annotations.lib
    base_prefs.lib
    cc_blink.lib
    command_buffer_common.lib
    gles2_utils.lib
    blink_platform.lib
    wtf.lib
    icui18n.lib
    icuuc.lib
    icudata.lib
    blink_common.lib
    skia_library.lib
    skia_opts.lib
    skia_opts_ssse3.lib
    skia_opts_sse4.lib
    zlib.lib
    zlib_x86_simd.lib
    sfntly.lib
    skia_chrome.lib
    skia_chrome_opts.lib
    blink_heap_asm_stubs.lib
    gles2_c_lib.lib
    command_buffer_client.lib
    libpng.lib
    libwebp_dec.lib
    libwebp_dsp.lib
    libwebp_utils.lib
    libwebp_demux.lib
    libwebp_enc.lib
    ots.lib
    brotli.lib
    qcms.lib
    url_lib.lib
    v8_base.lib
    v8_libbase.lib
    v8_snapshot.lib
    iccjpeg.lib
    libjpeg.lib
    harfbuzz-ng.lib
    blink_web.lib
    webcore_dom.lib
    translator.lib
    translator_lib.lib
    preprocessor.lib
    libxml2.lib
    libxslt.lib
    sqlite3.lib
    webcore_html.lib
    webcore_remaining.lib
    webcore_rendering.lib
    webcore_svg.lib
    webcore_generated.lib
    gin.lib
    snappy.lib
    modules.lib
    cc.lib
    command_buffer_service.lib
    disk_cache_proto.lib
    protobuf_lite.lib
    crcrypto.lib
    boringssl.lib
    re2.lib
    cityhash.lib
    gfx.lib
    base_i18n.lib
    gfx_geometry.lib
    gl_wrapper.lib
    gles2_cmd_helper.lib
    gpu_config.lib
    gpu_ipc.lib
    ipc.lib
    media.lib
    libyuv.lib
    opus.lib
    events_base.lib
    dom4_keycode_converter.lib
    shared_memory_support.lib
    libvpx.lib
    libvpx_intrinsics_mmx.lib
    libvpx_intrinsics_sse2.lib
    libvpx_intrinsics_ssse3.lib
    libvpx_intrinsics_sse4_1.lib
    media_asm.lib
    media_sse2.lib
    crash_component.lib
    crash_component_lib.lib
    breakpad_handler.lib
    sandbox.lib
    keyed_service_content.lib
    keyed_service_core.lib
    content_common.lib
    tracing.lib
    net.lib
    sdch.lib
    accessibility.lib
    ax_gen.lib
    ui_base.lib
    events.lib
    gesture_detection.lib
    events_platform.lib
    events_ipc.lib
    gfx_ipc.lib
    shell_dialogs.lib
    aura.lib
    compositor.lib
    cc_surfaces.lib
    metro_viewer_messages.lib
    win_window.lib
    metro_viewer.lib
    metro_viewer_constants.lib
    gpu_blink.lib
    gles2_implementation.lib
    gpu_skia_bindings.lib
    ipc_mojo.lib
    mojo_environment_chromium.lib
    mojo_environment_chromium_impl.lib
    mojo_common_lib.lib
    mojo_system_impl.lib
    mojo_cpp_bindings.lib
    mojo_application_bindings.lib
    storage.lib
    sql.lib
    storage_common.lib
    leveldatabase.lib
    webkit_gpu.lib
    ppapi_shared.lib
    surface.lib
    libjingle.lib
    rtc_base.lib
    rtc_base_approved.lib
    libjingle_p2p_constants.lib
    user_prefs.lib
    content_browser.lib
    device_vibration.lib
    device_vibration_mojo_bindings.lib
    device_battery.lib
    device_battery_mojo_bindings.lib
    google_apis.lib
    zip.lib
    minizip.lib
    snapshot.lib
    proto.lib
    speech_proto.lib
    content_common_mojo_bindings.lib
    power_gadget.lib
    mojo_js_bindings.lib
    http_server.lib
    printing.lib
    jingle_glue.lib
    desktop_capture.lib
    system_wrappers.lib
    desktop_capture_differ_sse2.lib
    iaccessible2.lib
    isimpledom.lib
    ppapi_ipc.lib
    flac.lib
    speex.lib
    navigation_interception.lib
    pdf_common.lib
    pdf_renderer.lib
    content_renderer.lib
    content_child.lib
    media_blink.lib
    mojo_js_lib.lib
    native_theme.lib
    libjingle_webrtc.lib
    libjingle_webrtc_common.lib
    libsrtp.lib
    media_file.lib
    video_capture_module_impl.lib
    video_capture_module.lib
    webrtc_utility.lib
    audio_coding_module.lib
    CNG.lib
    common_audio.lib
    openmax_dl.lib
    common_audio_sse2.lib
    G711.lib
    G722.lib
    iSAC.lib
    audio_decoder_interface.lib
    PCM16B.lib
    webrtc_opus.lib
    neteq.lib
    webrtc_video_coding.lib
    webrtc_i420.lib
    common_video.lib
    video_coding_utility.lib
    webrtc_vp8.lib
    webrtc_vp9.lib
    video_render_module_impl.lib
    video_render_module.lib
    usrsctplib.lib
    audio_processing.lib
    audioproc_debug_proto.lib
    audio_processing_sse2.lib
    libpeerconnection.lib
    voice_engine.lib
    audio_conference_mixer.lib
    audio_device.lib
    bitrate_controller.lib
    rtp_rtcp.lib
    paced_sender.lib
    remote_bitrate_estimator.lib
    rbe_components.lib
    webrtc.lib
    webrtc_common.lib
    video_engine_core.lib
    video_processing.lib
    video_processing_sse2.lib
    ppapi_host.lib
    ppapi_proxy.lib
    pref_registry.lib
    web_cache_renderer.lib
    web_cache_common.lib
    content_app_both.lib
    content_startup_helper_win.lib
    content_gpu.lib
    content_plugin.lib
    content_ppapi_plugin.lib
    content_utility.lib
    net_with_v8.lib
    sync_core.lib
    sync_proto.lib
    hunspell.lib
    webview.lib
    views.lib
    wm.lib
    version.lib
    usp10.lib
    psapi.lib
    dbghelp.lib
    shlwapi.lib
    cfgmgr32.lib
    powrprof.lib
    advapi32.lib
    gdi32.lib
    user32.lib
    kernel32.lib
    winspool.lib
    comdlg32.lib
    shell32.lib
    ole32.lib
    oleaut32.lib
    uuid.lib
    delayimp.lib
    netapi32.lib
    libcmt.lib
    libcpmt.lib
    OLDNAMES.lib
    winhttp.lib
    userenv.lib
    urlmon.lib
    dhcpcsvc.lib
    atls.lib
    wtsapi32.lib
    rpcrt4.lib
    libcef_dll_wrapper.lib
```